# do we always need to check if the pointer not a null after malloc/realloc?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, realloc

I am now studying C and in some code examples I saw that after we allocate some memory to a pointer, we have to check the pointer to be not a NULL. For example:

```
CVector *vector = malloc(sizeof(struct CVectorImplementation));
assert(vector != NULL);
```

another example:

```
vector->elements = realloc(vector->elements, vector->elemsz * vector->vec_capacity);
assert(vector->elements != NULL);
```

However, I think since the pointer is already been allocated, then it has the address of the allocated memory as its value, thus is it always necessary? why?

Comment: It is done to check if memory allocation is successful or not.

Comment: sidenote: assert is not a good way to check if memory allocation succeeded, assert is only valid in debug. you should do a if statement so that it works both in debug and release mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a great idea to check the pointer returned from malloc/realloc. 
If there's an error, you will get a null value returned. Use this check to your advantage because if you make reference to the same pointer later in your program and your program suddenly crashes, then chances are the pointer is set to null.

If you do have a valid pointer from a malloc/realloc call, then make sure you use it inside the `free()` function before deciding to modify the pointer value and before the program terminates, otherwise, you may run into memory leaks.

If you need to change the pointer value to write to a different section of the memory you allocated, then use another pointer.

Here's code in C that shows what I mean:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
  char *block=calloc(1,10000);
  if (block==NULL){
      printf("Can't allocate memory\n");
      return -1;
  }
  memset(block,48,20); //set 1st 20 bytes of memory to number zero (ascii code 48)
  char *insideoftheblock=block+10; // I set a pointer to go to index #10 in the memory
  *insideoftheblock='x';
  *insideoftheblock++;
  *insideoftheblock='y';
  printf("Memory = '%s'",block);
  free(block);
}
```

**P.S.**

I updated my code to include a check to see if memory has been actually allocated.

Answer (score 2):

If you've reassigned the original pointer in response to `realloc`, it's too late to do anything useful in response to a failure. When `realloc` fails, it returns `NULL`, but *it does not `free` the original pointer*. So even if you have some reasonable response to an allocation failure (not common), you've already leaked the memory you were trying to `realloc`.

The answer to your main question is mostly "it's a bad idea to allow `NULL` pointer dereferences to occur because it's a source of vulnerabilities"; usually the vulnerabilities crop up in kernel code (where `NULL` is just as valid an address as anywhere else), but even when it's not exploitable, it means the program segfaults instead of reporting an error in a useful way.

Answer (score 1):

The `realloc` function attempts to allocate new memory. If this allocation fails then the `realloc` function returns `NULL`. Your code must deal with this situation.

If you want to abort your program in this case then the `assert` as you currently have it is suitable.   If you want to recover, then you will need to store the `realloc` result in a separate variable while you assess the situation, e.g.:

```
void *new = realloc(vector->elements, vector->elemsz * vector->vec_capacity);
if ( !new )
    // take some action.... the old vector->elements is still valid
else
    vector->elements = new;
```

Comment: `new` is a horrible name to use :-)

Comment: @CyberSpock I think it's a good name,  it will weed out people using a different language's compiler to compile their C code!

Comment: yes that may be but it also is a non-descriptive name... "new" what? (nevermind, not important)

Comment: this makes sense. Thanks @M.M

Comment: My way to check without taking too much space is `if ((str = malloc((len +1 ) * sizeof(*str))) == NULL)


return (1); `

Comment: @Kotshi there's no prizes for using the fewest lines of code :)

Comment: @M.M I like it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

A failed allocation typical results in 1 of 2 actions:

1) Exit the program with a diagnostic.  This is far better than not checking and letting the code continue to who--knows--what.

2) In select circumstances, code can cope with the failure.  Maybe freeing other resources and trying again, return a failure code and leave the problem to the calling routine or writing a "suicide note" and re-starting the system.  IAC, the action is very specific to the situation.

Robust code checks the result.  Beginner code does not.